# How to add css with flask?

Tags: python, html, css, flask

could you, please, help me?

I'm trying to add a css file on a website.

This website was made by flask, html, css and uploaded on **HEROKU**.
When I was just in HTML, the homepage was working normally, now that I linked the css, I got this error:

**Internal Server Error**

*The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.*

When I move to other page without css, It works, but I don't know what's wrong.

**HTML:**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/reset.css') }}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/homepage.css') }}">

    <title>HomeD3v</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>nogD3V</h1>
    <h2>BUILDING</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

**PYTHON:**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def homepage():
    return render_template("homepage.html")


@app.route("/contatos")
def contatos():
    return render_template("contatos.html")


@app.route("/usuarios/<nome_usuario>")
def usuarios(nome_usuario):
    return render_template("usuarios.html", nome_usuario=nome_usuario)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

[STRUCTURE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UlOv7.png)

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and improve the question. Also, please include code not as an image file, but in code format. Thank you and good luck!

Comment: Did you try it in localhost server, with  `DEBUG=True` it gives you more information about the error

Comment: @MohammadRezaAram I tried and got the error, I didn't think about this. Bow, the homepage gone up, but the CSS changes didn't show!

127.0.0.1 - - [12/Jun/2022 22:26:33] "GET /static/css/reset.css HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [12/Jun/2022 22:26:33] "GET /static/css/homepage.css HTTP/1.1" 404 -

Comment: Can you post your code, and structure, Maybe CSS path isn't correct

Comment: I have just updated the question with the codes, could you see, please?

I don't think there's a problem with the css file 'cause there's jsut some changes about colors and resets and I got the error that it can't reload: HTTP/1.1" 40

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well in your case static directory should be in root of your project not inside the template directory, so it should be something like this

```
/
static/
     └── css/ 
           └──style.css
templates/
     └── base.html
main.py
```

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/styles.css')}}">`

In this link you can see flask project layout

https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.1.x/tutorial/layout/

Answer (score 0):

***I tried but It didn't work.***

```
127.0.0.1 - - [12/Jun/2022 23:34:48] "GET /static//static/reset.css HTTP/1.1" 308 -
127.0.0.1 - - [12/Jun/2022 23:34:48] "GET /static//static/homepage.css HTTP/1.1" 308 -
127.0.0.1 - - [12/Jun/2022 23:34:48] "GET /static/static/reset.css HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [12/Jun/2022 23:34:48] "GET /static/static/homepage.css HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

**And then I made some tests:**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='/static/reset.css') }}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='/static/homepage.css') }}">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/homepage.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/reset.css">
```

**and I got:**

```
127.0.0.1 - - [12/Jun/2022 23:34:48] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [12/Jun/2022 23:34:48] "GET /static/static/reset.css HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [12/Jun/2022 23:34:48] "GET /static/static/homepage.css HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [12/Jun/2022 23:34:48] "GET /static/homepage.css HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [12/Jun/2022 23:34:48] "GET /static/reset.css HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

**For some reason, I can't up files with the sintax: {{ url_for('static', filename='/static/reset.css') }}**

When I ran the code withou python sintaxe, the CSS showed on the page. But, why?

Comment: Change second static directory name to something else like `static/css/reset.css`

Comment: It didn't work. I'm going to keep the code like this, without python sintaxe for a while.

Thanks for the support!

Comment: I add more detail to answer, hope it gets clear for you